# How to remove overflow in print preview?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, plugins, printing

On print preview, how do you remove the overflow of a document? I've tried overflow:hidden with correct css syntax but it is not working. Thank you for your response.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in css.

```
overflow:auto;
```